# Getting stuck at implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I was given this following problem.

**Question**:
Let $$y=\sqrt{\cos{x}}.$$ First, show that $$ 4y^2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=1-y^4.$$ And consequently,

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{4}(y^{-3}+y).$$

Find the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$ at $x=0$.

If I just plow through the calculations (differentiating twice and subbed appropriate terms), I can  establish that the expression is indeed correct, and I can use them to calculate the derivatives.

**Alternative approach**
My questions surfaces when I tried another way. If I start from the 2nd equation and manipulated it, I obtain $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}(y^{-2}-y^2).$$ Differentiating both sides w.r.t $x$ gives $$ 2\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{y^3}+y)\frac{dy}{dx}.$$ Collecting the terms on the LHS gives $$ \frac{dy}{dx} \left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{y^3}+y\right)\right)=0.$$

At this point, I noticed that I could conclude what I wanted to prove if only $$ \frac{dy}{dx}\neq 0.$$

As $\frac{dy}{dx}=0 $ at $x=0$, I believe that this alternative approach cannot be used to show $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{4}(y^{-3}+y).$

So, my questions are

1. Am I incorrect to conclude that it doesn't work?
2. Is there a way to 'fix' this approach?

Thank you in advance for the read and responses.

Comment: $$\frac{\mathrm{d} ^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = \frac {\frac {-y^2}{2}-(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d} x})^2}{2y}$$

Comment: However, the better way would be to plugin $y=\sqrt {cos(x)}$ in the formula.

Comment: @FractalHand Thank you for the response. I do agree that doing that direct substitution will work. However, my main issue is about the validity of my conclusion of the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=\sqrt{g(x)}$, then $y'=\frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}$, and since $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$, the first identity is equivalent to:
$$ 4\cos x\left(\frac{-\sin x}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}\right)^2 = 1-\cos^2 x$$
that is just $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$. Since $y(0)=1$, the relation
$$ (2yy')^2 = 1-y^4 \tag{1}$$
gives:
$$ (2y'(0))^2 = 1-1=0,$$
hence $y'(0)=0$. Now we have:
$$ 8 y' y'' = y'(-2 y^{-3}-2y)$$
and since, due to $(1)$, $y'\neq 0$ in a punctured neighbourhood of the origin $U$, over $U$ we have:
$$ 4y'' = -y^{-3}-y\tag{2}$$
so if $y$ is a $C^2$ function in a neighbourhood of the origin, $y''(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ follows by evaluating $(2)$ in a point $\varepsilon$ near the origin then taking the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am I correct to say that your approach requires us to check if $y$ is actually twice differentiable inside the neighbourhood of the origin?